# How to increase the font size of the ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

I want to increase the font size of the rich text editor "ckeditor".

The first demo of this page (http://ckeditor.com/demo#toolbar) I am using. I want to make the font size of the body to say 44px.

I found this link http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbarGroups . It seems I can configure my font size from this page. But still could not point out which config is suitable to increase the font size.

Answer (score 4):

you can use setStyles function :

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        on: {
          instanceReady: function (evt) {
              evt.editor.document.getBody().setStyles({color: 'black', 'font-size': '72px'})
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a *contents.css* to modify the content displayed in the editor the default font and size:

```
body {
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 44px;
}
```

And setting :

```
config.font_defaultLabel = 'Arial';
config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '44px';
config.contentsCss
```

See the documentation :

- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss

Comment: in ckeditor 4.4.5 the font-size set in contents.css seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Open the contents.css inside the /ckeditor/ directory
And you can change font-size:

```
 background-color: #ffffff;
 font-size:16px; /* Just added this */
```

Comment: I found this link http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbarGroups . its seems i can configure my font size from this page. But still could not point out which config is suitable to increase the font size

Comment: in ckeditor 4.4.5 the font-size set in contents.css seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to modify the content displayed in the editor, customize [contents.css](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss).
- If you want to add some new, pre-defined styles to style combo, see the official [styles.js guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles).
- If you develop a plugin which adds some features that need styling, use [CKEDITOR.addCss()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-addCss) method.
- If you want to parse existing CSS file and use rules as pre-defined styles, see [stylesheetparser plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/stylesheetparser).

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your page

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
          on: {
              instanceReady: function (evt) {
                  evt.editor.document.getBody().setStyles({color: 'black', 'font-size': '18px', 'font-family': 'Verdana'})
              }
          }
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

i am using ckeditor 4.4.6 and changing content.css works,please note that changing the 'body' class  wont work , the '.cke_editable' class needs to be changed.

Comment: Maybe you could post a code example and more details to help the OP a little more?